# Is there a name for the function | L1 sect L2 | / | L1 |

Tags: distance-functions

I am not able to find an existing name for the comparison function I wrote.

I have two lists of values which I want to compare. At first I used jaccard, but then I recognized I need to eliminate the length of the second list as it does not seem to have anything to say in my use-case. So I changed jaccard to:

$$
sim(L1,L2) = \frac{|L1 \cap L2|}{|L1|}
$$

One example might be:

```
L1 = {name, test, somevalue}
L2 = {name, foo, bar, baz, some, random, other, values, which, would,
      flood, the, jaccard, comparison, as, they, are, too, much}
```

$$
sim(L1,L2) = \frac{|L1 \cap L2|}{|L1|} = \frac{|\{name\}|}{|\{name, test, somevalue\}|} = \frac{1}{3}
$$

To make a long story short, I only want to calculate how many percent of the values in L1 are in L2.
Does anybody know if there is a name for such a function so I can give it a good name within my source code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From where I stand it looks like the *conditional relative frequency* of $L2$ given $L1$.